# How to Merge Multiple Columns in to Two Columns based on Column 1 Value?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a text file in the below sample format

**File.txt**

```
Record1 20 23;
Record2 256;
Record3 45 679 98 1;
```

The no of columns in each line can vary. I want to change the file with only two columns based on column 1 Value. Below is the target output.

**File_2_Columns.txt**

```
Record1 20;
Record1 23;
Record2 256;
Record3 45;
Record3 679;
Record3 98;
Record3 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way

```
awk '{for(a=2;a<=NF;a++){printf "%s %s%c\n",$1,$a,a==NF ? "" : ";"}}' File.txt >File_2_Columns.txt
```

Good luck with the rest of your homework ;-)

If teacher is giving extra credits for shortest answer, try

```
awk '{for(a=2;a<=NF;){printf"%s%c\n",$1" "$a,a++-NF?";":""}}' File.txt >File_2_Columns.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Got a better idea on loops inside awk. Code makes a lot of sense.

Comment: ... or perhaps `'BEGIN{ORS=RS=";\n"} {for(a=2; a<=NF;) print $1,$(a++)}'`